# View a raw10 bit usb camera using OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision, color-space

I am trying to view the output of an Omnivision [OV7251](https://www.ovt.com/sensors/OV7251) camera in OpenCV 4.2.0 Python 3.5.6. The camera output is 10 bit raw greyscale data, which I believe is right aligned in 16-bit words.

When I use this OpenCV code:

```
import cv2

cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam2.set(3, 640)            # horizontal pixels
cam2.set(4, 480)            # vertical pixels

while True:
    b, frame = cam2.read()

    if b:
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(5)

        if k & 0xFF == 27:
            cam2.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

This is the image I get:

[image: OpenCV raw 10-bit OV7251]

Presumably what's happening is that OpenCV is using the wrong process to convert from 10-bit raw to RGB, believing it to be some kind of YUV or something.

Is there some way I can either:

- Tell OpenCV the camera's correct data format so that it does the conversion properly?
- Get hold of the raw camera data so that I can do the conversion manually?

Comment: Videos or photos? Documentation explicitly say "RAW"? (not something like "LOG")? For photo RAW is a sort of uncorrected RGB, but you get twice as much G, and colorimetry of filters (and intensity of each one) are different from sRGB. Videos has usually uncorrected (or linear) space, often 10bit, but it is not really a raw (so YCC). You should try with a patterns (bands with black, white and few grays + bands with full saturated colours), to get more information about colour encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to grab the raw camera data, then use numpy to correct it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam2.set(3, 640)            # horizontal pixels
cam2.set(4, 480)            # vertical pixels

cam2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False);          # Request raw camera data

while True:
    b, frame = cam2.read()

    if b:
        frame_16 = frame.view(dtype=np.int16)       # reinterpret data as 16-bit pixels
        frame_sh = np.right_shift(frame_16, 2)      # Shift away the bottom 2 bits
        frame_8  = frame_sh.astype(np.uint8)        # Keep the top 8 bits       
        img      = frame_8.reshape(480, 640)        # Arrange them into a rectangle

        cv2.imshow("Video", img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(5)

        if k & 0xFF == 27:
            cam2.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```